# In Oracle APEX 5.1, how can I create a form and report that gets criteria and output from Global Temp Tables?

Tags: stored-procedures, oracle-apex-5.1

I need to call a vendor procedure that searches the database for possible matches.  The input parameters are entered in a global temp table, then a procedure needs to be called that fills another global temp table with possible matches.  Any thoughts on the best way to do this with APEX?

This is a vendor database. I really can't change anything. The vendor procedure requires that I load parameters into their GTT, run their procedure, then get the results from their result GTT. I'm new to APEX and just trying to figure out the best way to handle that...what type of apex object do I use to load the parameters to the parameter GTT? How do I call the procedure when the parameter row is saved? What apex object should I use to display the result GTT...a report, a grid...?

Answer (score 0):

As data in a global temporary table (GTT) is "private", i.e. can be accessed in the same transaction or a session (which would probably be your choice, so you'd create a GTT with the `ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS`), as long as you do everything in the same session, that would work.

On the other hand, if there are several sessions involved, you're probably out of luck and will have to change the approach. The most obvious is to use a *normal* table (not a global temporary one), or - if possible - Apex collections.

Comment: This is a vendor database.  I really can't change anything.  The vendor procedure requires that I load parameters into their GTT, run their procedure, then get the results from their result GTT.  I'm new to APEX and just trying to figure out the best way to handle that...what type of apex object do I use to load the parameters to the parameter GTT? How do I call the procedure when the parameter row is saved? What apex object should I use to display the result GTT...a report, a grid...?